# SDL DXA and Adaptive layouts are not working

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-java, dxa-1.5

In my DXA 1.5 installation, I added two basic device families just to demo it and test it is working correctly

[image]

In the log files I see that it is resolving to the correct device type, in this case iphone

> This is an 'iphone' becuase of conditions.....

[image]

I've added views for Iphone and Ipad (article.iphone.jsp & article.ipad.jsp)

[image]

However I am always served the default view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an inconsistency in how DXA resolves normal and contextual views.

**Short story**

1. Set `dxa.web.views.folder=/` in `dxa.properties`.
2. Add your views to `<YOUR_WEBAPP>/src/main/resources/WEB-INF/Views/<PATH_TO_VIEW>`.

In your case: `/src/main/resources/WEB-INF/Views/Core/Entity/Article.iphone.jsp`.

Notice that this will brake contextual view resolve from modules. We **don't** have any in DXA though.

[Screenshot of my IDE](http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/2016/07/29/0000/1998/1998/98/a3469b0fe1.jpg)

---

**Long story**

Contextual views are being checked whether they exist in `classpath${dxa.web.views.folder}/WEB-INF/Views/<ViewName>`. `dxa.web.views.folder` is set to `/META-INF/resources/` by default, so for `Article.iphone` view the path is `classpath:/META-INF/resources//WEB-INF/Views/Core/Entity/Article.iphone.jsp`.

At the same time, ViewResolver tries to resolve the view from either `classpath:/WEB-INF` or `<webapp>/WEB-INF` (one level up from the classpath). For *JARs* it also tries `classpath:/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF`.

So while for views from JAR, both default check&resolve will find a JAR in a `/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF`, for web application check in `META-INF` will pass but resolve fail. You need either to set both to classpath root in a webapp or create your own module to solve this issue. See short story. :)

Comment: Thanks @Alexey - It seems I need to have the views in both places (unless I am doing something wrong). Without having `Article.iphone.jsp` in both `\src\main\resources\WEB-INF\Views\Core\Entity` and `\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\Views\Core\Entity` it does not work

Comment: The one in `\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\Views\Core\Entity` is used for rendering, but without the other one it always uses the default view

Comment: That's what I said actually. One from `webapp` folder is picked up by `ViewResolver` while the second is used for a check if you have a family-specific view. To solve that issue you need to point that check to your classpath root and put your view at the same place. This works perfectly for me: http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/2016/07/29/0000/1998/1998/98/a3469b0fe1.jpg